# Wifi adaptor isn't recognized on Pop OS! dual booted with windows 11 on Lenovo slim7 pro

Tags: wifi, pop-os, firmware

Need help figuring out how to connect my laptop to the WiFi while running Pop! OS.

- It's working when I switch to Windows.
- But when I open Pop! OS and try to try to connect to the WiFi, it says

  > No wifi adaptor found.

Also, I get a message to install a firmware, and I fail to proceed with the installation. I'm not sure if this is also related to the same problem.

[image: Pop-up dialog with message "Error in fwupd client: failed to GET firmware file from remote: https://fwupd.org/downloads/...: Dns Failed: resolve dns name 'fwupd.org:443': failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known: failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known]

P.S. I am a beginner linux user. This is my first linux distro to install.

Comment: Connect it via an ethernet cable then download?